# illegal characters in path using powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I need to verify one path using powershell. The problem is when given the path like `Test-Path -Path "\\\10.2.200.13\share\Logger\Logger"` its working fine, but my requirement is that, this path will be available in a Notepad - we need to read the path from the notepad then verify it. Here is the code:

```
$var = ( Get-Content D:\TestPathIssue\Params.txt ) -split '='
$source1=$var[1].Trim();
test-path -Path $source1;
```

I am able to get path in  `$source1` but I don't understand why its failing in `Test-Path` in this approach.

Comment: When you say `Notepad` do you really mean you need to get the path from a file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed by trying this-

```
$source1=$source1 -replace '"', ""
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if the variable **$source1** is returning path in quotes eg:- **"\10.2.200.13\share\Logger\Logger"** instead of **\10.2.200.13\share\Logger\Logger**

Comment: I am getting  "\\10.2.200.13\share\Logger\Logger" in variable $source1

Answer (score 0):

The following powershell code will take a list of legal characters with regex and report back on any non-legal characters found in filenames. Modify the list of legal characters as desired.

```
$legal = "[a-zA-Z\d\.\-'_\s\(\)&,%\[\];\!\$\+@~=#]"

ForEach ($File in Get-ChildItem -Path C:\mypath -Recurse){
  ForEach ($char in $File.Name.ToCharArray()){
    If ($char -notmatch $legal){
      $output = $char+" found in "+$file.fullname
      write-output $output
      break
    }  
  }
}
```